# How Would I Send Data To a Controller

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a forum, and I'm trying to implement a categories page. The page is working as of now, it's dynamic so it lists all categories stored in the database. However I want to be able to click on a category and be taken to a template page. From this template page I want to pass a `category ID` (defined in the database as a primary key). Then all posts with the matching category ID will be displayed. I'm having trouble passing this `category ID` to my category page template.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

(How categories are displayed in a list:)

```
@foreach($categories as $row)
    <div id="newscontainer" class="container">
        <?php $categoryid = $row->id; ?>
        <a href="/category"><span id='categoryname'><?= $row->categoryname ?><br></span></a>
        <span id="categorydescription"><?= $row->categorydescription?></span>
    </div>
    <br>
@endforeach
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who is having the same issue:
(I had a eureka moment...)

My `forums.blade.php` file (where the user selects the category they want to view:

Here, it's calling the category route (which is where the posts will be displayed) then it's setting the category ID in one url. It will look like this in the browser: www.example.test/category/(ID) (so when I query the database for posts under that category it will extract them).

`<a href="/category/{{ $categoryid }}"> <span id='categoryname'><?= $row->categoryname ?><br></span></a>`

My `web.php` file:

I basically grabbed the id from the URL which was passed through when the user clicked on the link.

`Route::get('/category/{id}', 'CategoriesController@getid');`

My `CategoriesController.php` file:

Here I have defined a function, so in the `web.php` it knows to go to the function with the attribute of `getid`. Once it has found the correct function it sets the `$catid` the same value as `$id`. Then it returns to the `categorytemplate` view (which is the template requiring the ID in the first place to display the posts) with the `$catid` variable in a `compact` function.

```
public function getid($id){
    $catid = $id;
    return view('categorytemplate', compact('catid'));
}
```

I hope my explanation is clear enough to understand. And I hope this can help someone else with this issue in the future!

Thanks again to everyone else suggesting ideas.

Comment: (Without going through a model).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a web route which will handle the category calls and return the view with that category and it's posts.

First you create a route like this:

```
Route::get('category/{category}', 'CategoriesController@show')->name('category.show');
```

Then you can access this `Category` inside the controller and load the posts and return them like this:

```
public function show(Request $request, Category $category) {
    return view('category.show', compact('category'));
}
```

Then in your view you would have something like this where you loop over available posts:

```
@foreach($category->posts as $post)
// do something
@endforeach
```

To call the route you can simply create this link:

```
<a href="{{ route('category.show', ['category' => $id]) }}">Show</a>
```

As I can see, your base namespace is `ULMG`, so the correct way to your `Category` class would be `ULMG\Category`

Comment: I keep on getting a `Class ULMG\Http\Controllers\Category does not exist` error?

Comment: This is because you need to import the model `Category` that you have inside the controller on the top of the class, where all other `use ...` are

Comment: Now a `Class Category does not exist`. Sorry if these are stupid mistakes I'm not picking up.

Comment: It's coming from `use category;` in the controller.

Comment: Category is a class so you need to create this class in order to be able to use it. Run `php artisan make:model Category` to create it

Comment: Now a `Class Category does not exist`

Comment: After creating the model.

Comment: After you created the model, you need to update that `use ...` on the top of the Controller to use the new correct model namespace

Comment: I have updated my answer, check the last line @UniversalLink

Comment: Fixed it, check my answer to see how I've done it. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all define a route in web.php:

web.php:

```
Route::get('category/{category}','YouController@YourCatFunction')->name('categories.list');
```

in your controller:

```
  public function YourCatFunction(Category $category)
  {
      // here you can return view for post with that category and then display them
     return $category;
  }
```

then in your view:

```
@foreach($categories as $row)
    <div id="newscontainer" class="container">
        <a href="{{ route('categories.list',$row->id)}}"><span id='categoryname'>{{ $row->categoryname }}<br></span></a>
        <span id="categorydescription">{{ $row->categorydescription }}</span>
    </div>
    <br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Error: `Class Category does not exist`

Comment: @UniversalLink have you imported your class ?

Comment: Yes I've imported my class.

Comment: `<?php

namespace ULMG\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use Category;


class CategoriesController extends Controller
{

 public function show(Request $request, Category $category) {

     return view('categorytemplate', compact('category'));

 }

}`

Comment: use App\Category;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181606/discussion-between-universal-link-and-salman-zafar).

Comment: Error `Class App\Category does not exist`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one as well.

Route `web.php`

```
Route::get('category/{categoryid}', ['as'=>'category.show','uses'=>'CategoriesController@show');
```

Controller `CategoriesController.php`

```
public function show($categoryid){
    // some of your code.
    $categoryid = DB::table('category')->select('categoryId');
    return view('category.show', compact('categoryId'));
   // don't forget if you have some variables and you want to view it at blade just put it inside the compact 
}
```

View blade `category.show.blade.php`

```
@foreach($categories as $row)
<div id="newscontainer" class="container">
    <a href="{{route('category.show',['categoryid'=>$row->categoryid])}}"><span id='categoryname'>{{ $row->categoryname }}<br></span></a> 
    <span id="categorydescription">{{ $row->categorydescription }}</span>
</div>
@endforeach
```